# place a search button on a fragments toolbar with an intent to an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I am trying to add a search icon on my fragment's toolbar.
This piece of code and the layout below just adds a menu icon(three vertical dots) on toolbar, and on pressing the menu, I get a `search`. 
But I dont want that. I am trying to have a search icon in the toolbar, with an intent to google [places autocomplete activity](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity). How I can do that?

**Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }
```

**map_menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="true"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Add `app:showAsAction="always"` to its menu `<item>`.

Comment: great....thanks. The icon is there, and while editing it , I get a editText like view. Can you kindly elaborate how I can add the Places autocomplete activity to this search?

Comment: If you mean [like this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity), then you don't want a `SearchView`. You just want a regular menu item, and then start the `PlaceAutocomplete` `Intent` from `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Comment: Oh, I guess you do say that in your question. Sorry, missed it. And Bhavik Makwana has that answer below. You'll still want the `showAsAction` attribute, though you'll have to provide your own icon.

Comment: Hi Mike, with all due respect and thanks to Bhavik, that was not my question what Bhavik has answered. That is the standard example in android's developer page. What I meant is once place is selected, then what? I mean any easy way to set that as location on MapFragment?

Comment: OK, your question says "I am trying to have a search icon in the toolbar, with an intent to google places autocomplete activity." That's what we've told you how to do. Remove the `actionViewClass` attribute, add the `showAsAction` attribute and your own `icon`, and start the `PlaceAutocomplete` `Intent` from `onOptionsItemSelected()` with `startActivityForResult()`. If you're also asking how to get the result, that's covered in the link - override `onActivityResult()`, then get the `Place` from the `data` `Intent`.

Comment: From that, you can [`getLatLng()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getLatLng()), if that's specifically what you're looking for. Otherwise, there's all sorts of [other information you can get from the `Place`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place#public-method-summary).

Comment: yes I understand. Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

from your menu item.

Add below code to show your menu item:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

and in click listener of the optionmenu Use PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder

```
int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
...
try {
    Intent intent =
            new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                    .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    // TODO: Handle the error.
}
```